# There is some error using gvim in Fedora15

Tags: vim, terminal, fedora, gnome

The os is Federa 15. gnome3. 
I install vim-X11 and input "gvim" in terminal.
the gvim can be used. But the terminal also output some error:

> (gvim:4431): Gdk-WARNING **: Using Cairo rendering requires the
>   drawable argument to have a specified colormap. All windows have a
>   colormap, however, pixmaps only have colormap by default if they were
>   created with a non-NULL window argument. Otherwise a colormap must be
>   set on them with gdk_drawable_set_colormap
>
> (gvim:4431): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_cairo_region: assertion `region
>   != NULL' failed
>
> (gvim:4431): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_cairo_region: assertion `region
>   != NULL' failed
>
> (gvim:4431): Gdk-WARNING **: Using Cairo rendering requires the
>   drawable argument to have a specified colormap. All windows have a
>   colormap, however, pixmaps only have colormap by default if they were
>   created with a non-NULL window argument. Otherwise a colormap must be
>   set on them with gdk_drawable_set_colormap
>
> (gvim:4431): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_cairo_region: assertion `region
>   != NULL' failed
>
> (gvim:4431): Gdk-CRITICAL **: IA__gdk_cairo_region: assertion `region
>   != NULL' failed

I don't know why?

Comment: You should probably ask this on Super User, since it's not programming-related.

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered this problem and get here by Google. In case anyone come later, you can remove the package `fcitx-frontend-gtk2` if you installed `fcitx`. The warnings and errors disappeared at once after I removed this package.